# 'Element "string" does not contain a definition ( c# WPF Problem )

Tags: c#, wpf

```
        private void loginBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string name = txtUsername.Text;
        string password = textPasswordBox.Password;
        if (string.name("Absolwent"));
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://dsc.gg/moonsense");
        }
    }
```

CS0117 'Element "string" does not contain a definition of "name".

I have a problem because I am trying to make a login panel, and I am currently fetching information from a text box in WPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use in your if statement:

```cs
if(name == "Absolwent") {
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://dsc.gg/moonsense");
}
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Can close this question